# Another Tumbleweed after Migration

Tags: bug, badges, migration

I asked for migration to Astronomy.SE of this [question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1821/what-happens-to-the-shrinking-universe-in-the-presence-of-the-pressure-of-hawkin), for which I already got a Tumbleweed badge on Physics.SE.

Right after migration I got another badge here. Is this a bug?

Further, there was a comment, shown in the [timeline](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/95701/timeline), which wasn't migrated. Why's that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the question *was* asked  more than a week ago, and had no answers. Migration doesn't change the date. I think this is expected behavior.

Comment: it could be unexpected behaviour because it hasnt existed ignored on *this* site for that long, i can see why recieving the badge would be misleading but without confirmation from anyone at SE i really can't say for certain

Comment: Would I get a [badge:popular-question] as well?